# Layout not adapting in chrome mobile emulator

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to build a responsive form for mobile first application but somehow its not working correctly.When i resize it in the browser it adapts correctly but when i use it in the chrome mobile emulator it does not adapt to screen size

[APPLICATION](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBLcw)

[FIDDLE DEMO ISOLATING FORM](http://jsfiddle.net/76zb286j/1/)

1. The margin attrib of `.row` class makes page margin negative why is this happening i am finding this perplexing
   [Margin negative](http://imgur.com/lhJQq4M)
2. Secondly in mobile view the pages are not rendering as when browser is resized to mobile size
3. Thirdly there is white space below the table

Why is this happening???

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">   <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></span>

                        <input type="text" id="gmap_where" name="gmap_where" class="form-control" placeholder="Where">  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="button2" class="btn   btn-success" onclick="findAddress(); return false;" type="button">Search for address</button>
                    </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gmap_keyword">Keyword (optional):</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="gmap_keyword" type="text" name="gmap_keyword" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gmap_type">Type:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="gmap_type">
                        <option value="art_gallery">art_gallery</option>
                        <option value="atm">atm</option>
                        <option value="bank">bank</option>
                        <option value="bar">bar</option>
                        <option value="cafe">cafe</option>
                        <option value="food">food</option>
                        <option value="hospital">hospital</option>
                        <option value="police">police</option>
                        <option value="store">store</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gmap_radius">Radius:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="gmap_radius">
                        <option value="500">500</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                        <option value="1500">1500</option>
                        <option value="5000">5000</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="40.7143528" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="-74.0059731" />
                <input type="hidden" id="FirstDestination" name="FirstDestination" value="" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="button1" class="btn btn-success" onclick="findPlaces(); return false;">Search for objects</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Here (Chrome 38 on Win7), when using the mobile emulator, the form resizes correctly

Comment: I am using an old machine with windows xp chrome version Version 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: does both the fiddle and codepen demo works fine for you ???

Comment: The codepen works fine, the fiddle also, but i have a strip on the left side of the form inside the result pane that's not showing (even on fullsize screen, non-emulator)

Comment: http://imgur.com/lhJQq4M ==> a missing strip (it shows 'yword' instead of 'keyword')

Comment: @sn_92 that is what i was saying in point 1

Comment: As a side critique, you should always place your CSS and JS/JQ in the appropriate sections on sites like Codepen. Makes it easier to see what's going on, and makes it so I don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom to find your markup. ;)

Comment: @MattD point duly noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<div class="container"></div>` around the HTML for the grid to solve the negative margin issue, and to get your rows to resize properly as the resolution changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/g6ft1tcv/

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jexlz

This is stated very clearly in bullet one regarding the grid system for Bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You can also use the class `container-fluid` if you want to make your form extend to the edges of the window/container without being cut off, if that's what you're wanting.

Anything else you need regarding margins/gutters/spacing should be answerable by reading the documentation for the Grid system, and possibly the documentation for Forms as well.

Comment: thanx i am little bit out of touch right now and regarding codepen that me being little lazy :P What i actually want to know is why is the fiddle showing horizontal scroll rather than resizing with respect to screen size

Comment: Because your margins are negative and push content outside the bounds of the window/frame on the right. If you contain your grid and form using a container div as outlined in my answer, all of your content is displayed, AND the scroll bar goes away. :)

Comment: As for why the Fiddle does it and Codepen doesn't, could just be the way each site has their rendering areas set up. Either way, add the div I noted (and which is required by the documentation) and you're good to go on either site, and should be good to go with your application.

Comment: +1 for solving the issue partially what i make of points 2 and 3 can be understood by checking out this link  http://imgur.com/6r9x7Vz  what i am trying to acheive is this http://imgur.com/DIuTPgI

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure I understand what the problems are.

Comment: I want to knwow why the text boxes are  rendering as this    http://imgur.com/6r9x7Vz and not like this http://imgur.com/DIuTPgI

Comment: Seems like that's more of a styling issue, so likely something to do with your CSS.

Comment: Check this out http://imgur.com/kBFzJ5F this is screenshot of responsive design at 320X480  in firefox browser where as this is http://imgur.com/W6lnWxq the same page at 320X480  resolution in mobile emulator of chrome

Comment: I think the key thing you're not understanding here is you're using an "emulator", which merely tries to work with the page as closely as it can for the device you're trying to test for, but that's about it: it tries, nothing more. Note that in Chrome, you can only change the resolution, where as in Firefox you're setting things based on the exact model of phone (unless that's just a name you assigned). The way one tool emulates an environment may be completely different in another tool. That's not something I can really account for.

Comment: You still having issues with this? Need any further clarification on something? The browser emulation issue is more an issue with how different browsers will render/handle things differently, especially when emulating another browser/system/environment/device.

Comment: @user3127499 Just came across this and remembered this question. Give it a look to see if it'll help solve your problem, if you're still having one. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972 I still feel you can't rely entirely on responsive design and emulator features of web browsers that aren't the one you're actually wanting to test, but it couldn't hurt.

Comment: the link that provided helped on addition of meta tags it rendered perfectly